# How do you add new or update existing object properties using lodash only or plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Say you have defined an object like:

```
let myObject = {};
```

And you were going to add unknown properties that may or may not already exist. To where `myObject` would look more like:

```
{
    foo: {
        prop: 'SOME PROP NAME',
        val:  'SOME VAL'
    },
    bar: {
        prop: 'SOME PROP NAME',
        val:  'SOME VAL'
    },
    baz: {
        prop: 'SOME PROP NAME',
        val:  'SOME VAL'
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `foo.prop` and `foo.val` may be set at different times. With props and vals set at the same time I'd probably just use _.assign() and maybe it's as simple as that with an extra layer added.

**Assume there is a function like:**

```
updateMyObject(e, attr, key) {
    myObject[attr][key] = e.target.value;
}
```

**Which obviously doesn't work**

I'm looking for a function that **would** work.

Comment: This should be an event listener function as well?

Comment: Have you tried with a Map? Like with `foo` as a key and `{prop:....val...}` as value. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before adding a new key and value, you can check if `myObject` contains `attr`, otherwise create it.

```
updateMyObject(e, attr, key) {
  if(!(attr in myObject))
    myObject[attr] = {};
  myObject[attr][key] = e.target.value;
}
```

Comment: I'll test this out... I'm also looking at lodash's `_.assignIn(object, [sources])`